# OptionsResolver : The option [...] does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

When I updated from Symfony3.4 to Symfony4.0 and verified the operation, the following error occurred.
It seems that the option setting is not working properly.
Do you have any idea?
I registered with `$resolver->setDefaults` by referring to other articles, but it didn't work.

Error

```
The option "mb_convert_kana_option" does not exist.
 Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".
```

ShopType.php

```php
    $builder->add("shopNameKana", TextType::class, array(
        "required" => false,
        "mb_convert_kana_option" => 'aCKV',
    ));

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            "data_class" => 'Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Entity\Shop',
            "attr" => array(
                "novalidate" => "novalidate",
                "autocomplete" => "off",
            ),
        //Tried Code
        'mb_convert_kana_option' => 'aKV',
        ));
```

src/Bundle/Form/Extension/MbConvertKanaExtension.php

```php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Perform the conversion using the options specified in
        if (isset($options['mb_convert_kana_option'])) {
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $data = mb_convert_kana($data, $options['mb_convert_kana_option'], 'UTF-8');
                $event->setData($data);
            });
        }
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'mb_convert_kana_option' => 'aKV',
        ));
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }
```

Comment: In Symfony 4 you need to use getExtendedTypes instead of getExtendedType https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/create_form_type_extension.html#defining-the-form-type-extension

Comment: @Vyctorya Thanks for your comment. This app is Symfony 4.0, so it seems that it needs to be ```getExtendedType()```. However, thanks to you, I was able to arrive at the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not set extended_type in service.yaml  .
The error disappeared by modifying it as follows.

https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/form/create_form_type_extension.html#registering-your-form-type-extension-as-a-service

```yaml
    common.form.extension.mbConvertKanaExtension:
        class: Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Form\Extension\MbConvertKanaExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType }
```